# Appcelerator android button title lowercase works only on app restart

Tags: android, button, themes, appcelerator

I have problem with Android Theme personalization. 
I have MyTheme.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and inside tiapp.xml

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:versionCode="14" android:versionName="1.0">
        <application android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
            <activity
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        </application>
        <!--<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>-->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
        <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="18" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <!-- Allows the API to access Google web-based services -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <!-- Specify OpenGL ES 2.0 as a requirement -->
        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

The problem is that at first run, the buttons are allCaps, but if I kill the app and restart it buttons become lowercase. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

why not set lowercase text programmatically? `button.setText("your string".toLowerCase());`

Comment: I use lowercase text but Android Theme force to AllCaps. I want that theme respect my text, lowercase, uppercase, camel case etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>`
instead of `<item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. The sensation is that mytheme.xml isn't loaded at first run but only when I put the app in background and I reopen it... . Simulator or device is the same.

Comment: Don't know why this should happen, it sounds really weird.
1.
Ensure your theme is in the correct folder:
/project/app/platform/android/res/values

2.
Clear build folder.

Comment: I notice that the problem is only for the buttons inside a listview. Mh...

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that probably is a bug for buttons inside list view.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19629